# Elegant Way to Combine Large CSV Files using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a routine to append Large CSV Files into one file. Im tracking the number of data frames so that I will not repeat the header for the next appends. This is currently working but I'm wondering if there is a better way to write this code.

```
    init = 0
    #combined all files in a list
    for file in csv_files:
            chunk_container = pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=CHUNK_SIZE)
            # export to csv
            for chunk in chunk_container:
                if init == 0:
                    chunk.to_csv(output_file, mode="w", index=False)
                else:
                    chunk.to_csv(output_file, mode="a", index=False, header=None)
                init += 1
```

Comment: pandas requires that the data be read into memory, so you may hit a MemoryError trying to do this will large files.  If you don't need to manipulate the files with pandas your probably better off using standard python

Comment: Why will I hit a memory Error? Based on my observation It doesn't consume much memory since it is writing the df to the output file itself. It is writing directly to the disk space.

Comment: depends on the size of your files. `pd.read_csv()` will read the whole file into memory, not stream to file.

Comment: But isn't the chunking help for that memory limitation? I'm asking because I'm a bit new to python to have better ways to improve it. Thanks

Comment: "LARGE" is relative. If LARGE is 100MB you may not have an issue.  If LARGE is 100GB you probably will.

Comment: Ok I will keep this in mind. Actually I'm just trying to have something that looks like the batchscript from windows of  ```copy "*.csv" "Combine.csv" without the header repetition. I think this is much faster compare to my existing routine.

Comment: yes, if you concatenate the files together at the os level it will probably be much faster than if you write a program.